# Cant debug angularjs app with maven

Tags: java, angularjs, maven, guacamole

Im trying to debug an all together java app with angularJS using maven and jetty but failing to get dynamically generated app.js and app.css files.

On the java app I have:

```
  Collection<Resource> javaScriptResources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    javaScriptResources.add(new WebApplicationResource(getServletContext(), "/guacamole.js"));

  Collection<Resource> cssResources = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    cssResources.add(new WebApplicationResource(getServletContext(), "/guacamole.css"));

  serve("/app.js").with(new ResourceServlet(new SequenceResource(javaScriptResources)));
  serve("/app.css").with(new ResourceServlet(new SequenceResource(cssResources)));
```

These two files are generated by the `minify-maven-plugin` and the location is `<webappSourceDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappSourceDir>`, it works great when I run the `package` maven command and generate the `.war` file and put in the webapps tomcat folder.

But when I try to debug with IntelliJ using the `jetty` plugin i get a `NullPointerException`.I think its because the `guacamole.js` and the `guacamole.css` files are in the maven `target` folder, and the java app tries to find it inside the webapp path. How to fix that?

[image: here are the files] but only in the target folder.